# Grafana Loki does not delete logs after retention delete delay

Tags: grafana-loki

I have installed Grafana Loki with docker.
I can store my logs and see them with Grafana. It's cool.
But I am not able to delete logs after a specific amount of time.

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

common:
  path_prefix: /loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093

analytics:
  reporting_enabled: false

compactor:
  working_directory: /loki/retention
  shared_store: filesystem
  compaction_interval: 2m
  retention_enabled: true
  retention_delete_delay: 1m
  retention_delete_worker_count: 150


limits_config:
  retention_period: 2h
```

retention_delete_delay: 1m does not work. Apparently the logs will be deleted after approximately 2h. I don’t know what is causing this tho.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I don't understand your intention, or you don't understand what `retention_delete_delay`. It being `1m` means that logs will be actually deleted only one minute later, after their retention period (`2h`) elapsed. It seems you evidence this behavior. So what's the problem?

Comment: I would like my logs to be deleted after 2 hours and immediately. But the logs that must be deleted are kept for 2 hours longer. So I can see 4 hours of log and not 2 hours.